# How to configure Quality Gate on SonarQube

Tags: sonarqube

I tried updating rules with SonarQube, it is working, and it will update 'A', 'B', 'C' grade,

but not currently it is failing on 'C', I wanted to fail on 'B' grade.

where I can find this option to configure at sonarqube.

any help would be appreciated thanks

Answer (score 0):

Uses with the `Administer Quality Profiles and Gates` permission are able to manage (create/delete/modify) Quality Gates. You have to open `Quality Gates` from the top menu, choose the one which you want to edit and then in the form change the grade fromk `C` to `B`.

If you don't want to change the existing Quality Gates, you have to create a new one and then assign it to your project: open your project → click `Project Settings → Quality Gate` and choose the new one.